# T minus time to ransom!

Tags: code-golf

The WannaCrypt ransomware has struck and it is attacking networks right, left and center. A network is defined by an m*n binary matrix (a),  which has a a[i][j] = 1 if a computer is infected and a[i][j] = 0 if it is not. At the end of each hour, all computers that are a neighbour (which shares a side or a corner with) of an infected computer are infected by the ransomware..

Your job is to calculate the time after which all computers in the network will be infected by the virus.

Also, do keep in mind that the shortest code wins.

### Input

The first 2 lines contains the values of m and n respectively.
The next m lines contain a binary string of length n corresponding to the computers of the network.

### Output

An integer which is equal to the mumber of hours after which the whole network will be infected by the ransomware.

### Input Constraints

1 <= m,n <= 1000

## Sample Test Cases

### Test Case 1

Sample Input

```
2
2
11
11
```

Sample Output

```
0
```

### Test Case 2

Sample Input

```
3
4
0101
0001
0001
```

Sample Output

```
2
```

### Test Case 3

Sample Input

```
2
2
10
00
```

Sample Output

```
1
```

P.S: Take input in any format that doesn't violate the ordering of [m,n,matrix]
P.P.S: m and n are optional inputs. The only compulsory input is the matrix.

Comment: Can we take it as an array instead? i.e. `[2, 2, "11", "11"]` for JavaScript. People don't like having to spend bytes parsing input, usually

Comment: yes. that works.

Comment: Can we take the matrix as a matrix, instead of row by row?

Comment: I've incorporated an additional condition. As long as it doesn't affect the variables, m,n and matrix can be taken in any reasonable format.

Comment: Do we *have to* take the dimensions? Most languages will be able to handle input without that information, and not using it might be even shorter.. Also, do sides/corners wrap around?

Comment: It makes it computationally easier if the dimensions are there. But do you think the challenge will be better if that part is removed?

Comment: The challenge would be better with that part optional.

Comment: @Rod the sandpile problem is a state calculation problem. Plus, there the origin point can change and at every second may affect multiple points which may not even be its neighbour. This is a time calculation problem, plus once a ripple has passed through it's neighbours, that state is fixed and cannot be changed. I don't see how they are related. Could you please explain?

Comment: So this is a maximum filter (with a 3x3 kernel) iteration counter?

Comment: @KoishoreRoy fair enough

Comment: @GáborFekete It's more like a longest path calculator. If you want to approach the problem from a different perspective i.e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Octave, 26 bytes

```matlab
@(a)max(bwdist(a,"ch")(:))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRMzexQiOpPCWzuEQjUUcpOUNJU8NKU/N/mq1CYl6xNRdXmka0oYIhl4KCApCK1QQLGADZBhBBAzBEZkLVAFVABWM1/wMA)

Explanation:

Computes maximum of the chessboard distance transform of the binary matrix.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 90 bytes

```python
g=lambda a:min(min(a))or-~g(map(lambda*c:map(max,(0,)+c[:-1],c,c[1:]),*a))
lambda a:g(a)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoMwDER3voIxpkY4jJH6JVEGN4gUqQkRYqBLfz01MKB2sGXfu7v8Xp9z6ksJ9xfHx8A1mzgltQ8DzEv7CSpyVidtvNmfyBsqQrh5a1rt0KO32jjARjLVeFUFKen6kpcprfWorNUo9mM7qC6ZUCMdiJD@rh@j2E4kcvkC)

Accepts a matrix as a list of lists of 0 and 1.

#### How it works

```python
g=lambda a:min(min(a))or…
```

If the smallest element of the matrix is 1 (it is completely infected), return 1; otherwise…

```python
                        -~g(…                                            )
```

return 1 plus the recursive result on the following modified matrix…

```python
                            map(lambda*c:…                           ,*a)
```

for each old *column* `c`…

```python
                                         map(max,(0,)+c[:-1],c,c[1:])
```

produce a new *row* by zipping `max` over the down-shifted, original, and up-shifted versions of `c`.  (`map` fills in the gap at the end of `c[1:]` with `None`, which is falsy and smaller than both `0` and `1`.)

Each iteration of `g` computes all vertical infections, then transposes the matrix.  This way, every 2 iterations of `g` compute all horizontal, vertical, and diagonal infections.

```python
lambda a:g(a)/2
```

Because the base case of `g` with a fully infected matrix gave 1 rather than 0, the parity works out such that floored division by 2 always gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 127 bytes

```
function(x,y,m){a=which(m);b=cbind(a%/%x+1,(a-1)%%x+1);for(i in 1:x)for(j in 1:y)m[i,j]=min(apply(abs(b-c(i,j)),1,max));max(m)}
```

For each clean computer (`0`), checks what the closest infected computer is. Outputs the maximum value, because that is how long it would take for the infection to reach it.

It is a function that takes the number of rows `x`, the number of columns `y` and the matrix `m` as input. More explanation follows when I get home.

```
function(x,y,m){                     A function taking 3 arguments
  a=which(m)                         Take the indices of matrix m containing 1 (TRUE). This
                                     implicitly turns m into a vector, so a contains all 
                                     the wrapped indices.
  b=cbind(a%/%x+1,(a-1)%%x+1)        Turn a back into i and j indices for 1s in m.
  for(i in 1:x)                      Loop over all rows
    for(j in 1:y)                    Loop over all columns
      m[i,j]=                        Assign in m[i,j] the following:
      min(                           Take the lowest value of the vector created below v
      apply(abs(b-c(i,j)),1,max));   Take the absolute difference between (i,j) and all 
                                     (x,y) where m[x,y] == 1. Take the rowwise maximum
                                     to find the distance between (i,j) and all the 1s in m
  max(m)}                            Return the maximum distance.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 181 bytes

```
import numpy as n,scipy.ndimage.filters as s
g=lambda m=n.asarray(list(map(int,list(i))for i in input().split())),i=0:g(s.maximum_filter(m,3),i+1)if n.count_nonzero(m)<m.size else i
```

Recursively calls itself until each element is 1 and returns the iteration count. Accepts input as a string: `"0101\n0001\n0001"`